# Wrong path on image loaded from SDcard

Tags: java, android, image, path, gallery

I have a problem with my image gallery. Im using [Dreddik's TouchImageGallery Library](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery) . Im trying to load images from sd card folder. When I try to load an image from internet url It works, but it dont do that when I pass an image path  from my sd card.

I think the issue may be the file path, but I have no found info about this. I'm using "raw paste" technique, but I think I'm wrong with that.

I paste you my code below:

MainActivity:

```
public class GaleriaMainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_galeria_main);

        String []rutas = {"/storage/sdcard0/bola2.jpg", 
            "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1334835629645.jpg" };

        Intent i = new Intent(this, CargadoDesdeSd.class);
        i.putExtra("src", rutas);
        startActivity(i);

}

}
```

And this is the class who retrieves the image's paths from the main:

```
public class CargadoDesdeSd extends Activity {

private String[] imgPaths;
private GalleryViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_cargado_desde_sd);
imgPaths = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("src");
Log.d("debug", imgPaths[0]);

String []urls = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("src");
//  String []urls = {
//                "http://www.holafamilias.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/hola-11.jpg",
//                "http://cs407831.userapi.com/v4078f31207/18fe/4Tz8av5Hlvo.jpg",
//                "http://cs407831.userapi.com/v407831207/1906/oxoP6URjFtA.jpg",
//                "http://cs407831.userapi.com/v407831207/190e/2Sz9A774hUc.jpg",
//                "http://cs407831.userapi.com/v407831207/1916/Ua52RjnKqjk.jpg",
//                "http://cs407831.userapi.com/v407831207/191e/QEQE83Ok0lQ.jpg"};

    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(items, urls);

    UrlPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new UrlPagerAdapter(this, items);
    pagerAdapter.setOnItemChangeListener(new OnItemChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemChange(int currentPosition)
        {
            Log.d("debug","Current item is " + currentPosition);
        }
    });

    mViewPager = (GalleryViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewer);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
}
```

Anyone knows why this happends?

Thanks very much!!! :)

**EDIT**
This is what logcat says:

```
05-30 12:02:37.085: W/System.err(24489): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1338473970511.jpg
05-30 12:02:37.085: W/System.err(24489):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:178)
05-30 12:02:37.085: W/System.err(24489):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
05-30 12:02:37.085: W/System.err(24489):    at ru.truba.touchgallery.TouchView.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:87)
05-30 12:02:37.090: W/System.err(24489):    at ru.truba.touchgallery.TouchView.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:1)
05-30 12:02:37.100: W/System.err(24489):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-30 12:02:37.100: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-30 12:02:37.100: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-30 12:02:37.100: W/System.err(24489):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-30 12:02:37.100: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-30 12:02:37.100: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-30 12:02:37.100: W/System.err(24489):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-30 12:02:37.100: D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(2119): enqueueToast()
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1334835629645.jpg
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:178)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at ru.truba.touchgallery.TouchView.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:87)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at ru.truba.touchgallery.TouchView.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:1)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/bola2.jpg
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:178)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at ru.truba.touchgallery.TouchView.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:87)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at ru.truba.touchgallery.TouchView.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:1)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-30 12:02:37.105: W/System.err(24489):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**EDIT:**
I have realize that I was trying to load SDcard images from URL image loader class. I have reorientated it, and now this is my main activity code show below:

```
    /*
*Fields
*/

final String TAG= "debug";
private GalleryViewPager mViewPager;
private String[] imgPaths;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
imgPaths = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("src");
Log.d(TAG, imgPaths[0]);
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
int readLimit = 16 * 1024;
try {
for (String filename : imgPaths) 
{
if (filename.matches(".+\\.jpg")) 
{
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(filename, "")), readLimit);
    is.mark(readLimit); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
copy(is, new File(filename) );
items.add(filename);
}
}
} catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

FilePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new FilePagerAdapter(this, items);
pagerAdapter.setOnItemChangeListener(new OnItemChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemChange(int currentPosition)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current item is " + currentPosition);
    }
});

mViewPager = (GalleryViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewer);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


public void copy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException 
{
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
}
```

I haven't runtime errors, but it displays an default error image and doesn't show images that I want :\

Answer (score 1):

Do not use your SD Card path like this

use this

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String folder = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolder" ;
```

**As per your comment**

```
path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
```

**Edit: As per the [link](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery/blob/master/library/src/ru/truba/touchgallery/TouchView/FileTouchImageView.java) provided in the comments**

```
FilePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new FilePagerAdapter(this, items);
    pagerAdapter.setOnItemChangeListener(new OnItemChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemChange(int currentPosition)
        {
            Toast.makeText(GalleryFileActivity.this, "Current item is " + currentPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mViewPager = (GalleryViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewer);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

For more information please visit this [link](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery/blob/master/example/src/ru/truba/touchgallery/GalleryFileActivity.java), which talks about how to use a *local file based image* rather than, web based image.

Comment: The point is that I need to load them from the string array with paths that I've just passed through the intent.

I have tried it with no success. This is how it looks like:

`code

    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String folder = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera" ;
    String []rutas = {"1338473970511.jpg", 
    "1334835629645.jpg"};
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GalleryUrlActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("src", rutas);
    startActivity(i);`

Comment: It didn't but I have rewatch it and I have realized that it calls `URLTouchImage` (https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery/blob/master/library/src/ru/truba/touchgallery/TouchView/UrlTouchImageView.java) and it tries to load a pure web file, so I think that is why it throws that exception.
It has other related class, `FileTouchImageView` (https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery/blob/master/library/src/ru/truba/touchgallery/TouchView/FileTouchImageView.java), so I'm going to research about this and, if I encounter a solution, I`ll post it here later.
Anyway very thanks to both! :)

Comment: @leonis Actually I found the solution. If you haven't should I guide you? Based on your link

Comment: Of course ! Every help is always welcome! :p 

And thanks in advance! @MDMalik

Comment: @leonis please have a go through

Comment: I think I must create an InputStream from the sdcard-image path, and later give that InputStream to copy method.

I have tried this: `final int readLimit = 16 * 1024; for (String filename : imgPaths) { if (filename.matches(".+\\.jpg")) { InputStream is = null; try { is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(filename, "")), readLimit); is.mark(readLimit); } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } copy(is, new File(filename) ); items.add(filename); } }` I have no runtime error, but it doesnt load my images, it loads an default error image :\

Comment: Do a Log.i of your fileName to see your file

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

to get the root path of your sd folder.

Comment: Sorry for the format :s

  `code
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String folder = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera" ;
    String []rutas = {"1338473970511.jpg", 
    "1334835629645.jpg"};
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GalleryUrlActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("src", rutas);
    startActivity(i);`

Comment: Don't use the absolute path... try to open the file directly :

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM/Camera";

Comment: No I don't, I used the variable sdCard to storage Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

And I have the same result :\